# How to format multiple errors per property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

Given a view with this:

```
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount)
            <span>$</span> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount)
```

I have a view model with an Amount property that I'm validating with this code:

```
 public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

        var amt = Amount.ToString();
        var amtParts = amt.Split('.');
        String amtErrs="";

        if (amt.Contains("-"))
        {
            amtErrs += "Negative fees are not allowed.<br>";
        }
        if (!amt.Contains("."))
        {
            amtErrs += "Please enter how many pennies.<br>";
        }
        if (amt.Contains(".") && amtParts[1].Length < 2 )
        {
            amtErrs += "Please enter both tenths and ones for cents.<br>";
        }
        if (amt.Contains(".") && amtParts[1].Length > 2)
        {
            amtErrs += "Please no splitting pennies.<br>";
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(amtErrs))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult(amtErrs, new String[] { "Amount" });

        }

    }
```

The ValidationMessageFor seems to be encoding the break tags.

How do I achieve the desired effect of having each error on its own line?

Comment: Use `Environment.NewLine` and then style the `<span>` element generated by `ValidationMessageFor()` - `display: inline-block; whitespace: pre;`

Comment: Awesome! that works! appreciate the quick response Stephen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` (like all the html helper's except `Raw()`) encodes the output.

In your `Validate()` method, replace `<br/>` with `Environment.NewLine` and in the view use css to style the `<span>` element generated by `ValidationMessageFor()` to display multiple lines.

```
.field-validation-error > span {
    display: inline-block;
    whitespace: pre;
}
```